# Need help identifying helmet

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

I cannot identify this minifigure helmet I have. It looks like some sort of a biker helmet.

This piece came in a bulk of parts, which are LEGO, however not entirely sure this is legit LEGO piece. It fits snugly onto minifigure head, however doesn't have any usual LEGO marking. The inside has just a number "3". Which is the reason for [clone-brands](/questions/tagged/clone-brands) tag. I did check on Bricklink, but I'm not very familiar with minifigure items.

[image][image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to part# 30171 [Minifigure, Headgear Cap, Aviator](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30171#T=C&C=11)

[image]

In black it appears in [118 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=30171&colorID=11&in=A).

However, I checked with my helmet from [Robo Pilot](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=tlm065#T=I) 
and that one has a LEGO marking on the inside, yours could be a older mold though.

- Edit, I also have one with a 7 marking inside , no logo, so I would assume it is from an older mold.

Comment: Ah, so "Aviator" is a key word here. It turns out I already had a this piece in LEGO set from 2011. Both of the items have a number inside without mentioning LEGO anywhere. Also moulds are the same, including PIP, which proves this is LEGO piece after all.