# Are there LEGO pieces without "LEGO" logo?

Tags: part-identification

I have a LEGO wizard, the green one with a wizard hat that has a dragon on it but the hat doesn't have a "LEGO" logo on it. Also the beard. But the rest of the torso and legs have markings on them. Are the hat and beard fake?

Comment: Is this a question about specific items you have mentioned or you'd want to know which LEGO elements have no marking on them?

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE.  A more general discussion of this question can be found at https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/15101/which-parts-do-not-have-the-lego-logo-stamped-on-them .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I identify a LEGO part?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/154/how-do-i-identify-a-lego-part)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which parts do not have the LEGO logo stamped on them?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/15101/which-parts-do-not-have-the-lego-logo-stamped-on-them)

Answer (score 1):

Some Lego parts don't have a logo on them, depending on the mold.

Like the helmet in this question

[Need help identifying helmet](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/14649/need-help-identifying-helmet)

your figure is probably this

[Part 6131pb03 : Minifigure, Headgear Hat, Wizard / Witch with Black Buckle and Gold Dragon Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=6131pb03&colorID=80&in=A)

[image: Part 6131pb03]

from
[cas435 - Dark Green Wizard](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=cas435#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
[image]